# Where does joomla store the sef urls?

Tags: joomla, sef

I've just uninstalled **mijosef** from my site because i hated the way it rename my `sef urls`, but now my originals `sef urls` doesn't come back, where does ***joomla*** store the `sef urls`? in the database? in a file? or where?

I've tried to restore my site with akeeba backup, but the problem persist, and i'm not able to find any references to the sef urls in the database.

Comment: They are not stored anywhere. Try clearing your browser cache and changing the previously generated links in your menus that you are probably clicking on.

Comment: i've tried that but doesn't work

Comment: Show us a sef link that you want to change. How do you access them?

Comment: This is a link http://www.teslabem.com/tienda/product/50-1016 before mijosef the link was http://www.teslabem.com/tienda/1016

Comment: I don't see a *real* problem since the second url seems to be shortened (rewritten) as it's probably not the proper way to address the product. I'd suggest contacting the developer.

Comment: I use the format <http://teslabem.com/tienda/product-id> because I use another short domain that redirects my customers to the product specs, I mean, if i have a motor with id 1024 then i put a label in the product like <http://tbem.us/1024>

Comment: and i cant contact the developer since i used the free version of mijosef, I would wanna change the sef urls by myself but I cant find them

Answer (score 1):

Joomla's SEF URLs are not stored in the database but rather based on the menu structure of the site. You can find more details at http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't say anything about how to change the sef urls, i' want to change the mijoshop sef urls.